# Python requests to online store not checking out

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, url, python-requests

I am new here so bear with me if I break the etiquette for this forum. Anyway, I've been working on a python project for a while now and I'm nearing the end but I've been dealing with the same problem for a couple of days now and I can't figure out what the issue is.

I'm using python and the requests module to send a post request to the checkout page of an online store. The response I get when i send it in is the page where you put in your information, not the page that says your order was confirmed, etc.

At first I thought that it could be the form data that I was sending in, and I was right. I checked what it was supposed to be in the network tab on chrome and i saw I was sending in 'Visa' and it was supposed to be 'visa' but it still didn't work after that. Then I thought it could be the encoding but I have no clue how to check what kind the site takes.

Do any of you have any ideas of what could be preventing this from working? Thanks.

EDIT: I realized that I wasn't sending a Cookie in the request headers, so I fixed that and it's still not working. I set up a server script that prints the request on another computer and posted to that instead and the requests are exactly the same, both headers and body. I have no clue what it could possibly be.

Comment: Could be almost anything.  Are you doing a get before the post?  Does the site require you to log in first, and are you doing that? Is the site expecting to set a cookie?  Are you sending a user-agent header?

Comment: You don't need to log in. I'm not sure about the cookie how would I find that out? And if you mean in the headers about the user agent then yes.

Comment: Do that online store provide APIs to integrate?

Comment: I doubt it. It's not really meant to be integrated with programs like mine.

Comment: I don't think it's the encoding either. The encoding shown in firebug is the same as what requests is sending.

Comment: Are you using a session?

Comment: Yes I am using a session and the item that I add to cart earlier is still there right before I check out so it's keeping the session.